# Can I use git in local area network?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I want to use EGit in a small eclipse project with my colleagues, but we don't want to Submit the project to the github.com. What I should do with the next picture ?
The ip address is 192.168.16.40 and the project is in D:\EclipseProjects\ForwardA.git.

How I should fill the URI,Host,Repository Path ?

Is the Authentiacation for the computer or git ?

[image]

Comment: You don't want to clone a remote repository if you're starting a brand new repository.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can!  Github is a common centralized repository that git enthusiasts use frequently, but it's by no means required to use git.  You can even use git on a computer that has no Internet access whatsoever.

You have many options for setting up your git repository, but you probably want to pick a Unixy server that all of your colleagues have access to.  From there, you have a few setup options, but the easiest way is to just pick a directory that they all have access to and stick a headless git repository at.

Here's a good resource on the subject: http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_private_repository.html

Comment: How I should fill the URI,Host,Repository Path ?

Is the Authentiacation for the computer or git ?

Comment: It depends on how you set up your git repo, but the authentication is for the computer.  It sounds like you really need to read a tutorial on the subject.  It'll be way easier than figuring it out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You most definitely can, I'm not sure if you already have a git server set up with your friend.
If not you can follow this very handy tutorial I myself used:
**[Setting up a Msysgit Server with copSSH on Windows](http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/)**.

If you do have a server you will need:

- the IP address of the computer the repository is on,
- its path relative to the computer,
- the SSH(or whatever protocol you use) port number and
- the authentication.

The `auth` field should be the user on the Git server that has access to the git repo, I set it to admin in my example but I'm guessing anyone that has R/W access to the folder can manipulate it.

I'm going to throw a wild guess as to how to complete this form:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Gitblit](http://gitblit.com) is an open-source, integrated, pure Java Git server, viewer, and repository manager for small workgroups.  It works well on Windows and includes tools to run as a Windows service.